# using bootstrap over multiple columns

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using the bootstrap framework and want to use the three column layout.

```
    <div id="intro" class="row">    
    <div class="col-md-4">  . . . paragraph 1 . . . </div>  
    <div class="col-md-4"> . . . paragraph 2 . . . </div>  
    <div class="col-md-4"> 
        <?php if ( !function_exists('dynamic_sidebar')
            || !dynamic_sidebar("widgets") ) : ?>  
        <?php endif; ?>     
      </div>
    </div>
```

I want only one paragraph per column and then it gets moved to the second column, third column etc. I don't have full control of the content other than amount of paragraphs (if there was a method that could do even paragraphs dynamically would be great)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried wrapping the text using css? You can also use the `<pre>` element.

http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_typography.asp

Comment: I mean the content is generated through Wordpress by a widget, I can't put certain text in certain paragraphs. I figure I am looking for a javascript answer